# "If you were not expecting to see this page, check out the activation guide for more information"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am deploying a web app on GAE. App uses Task Queues and Datastore.
I do NOT need Compute Engine. Why do I get this message when I try to launch
my app after deploying on GAE ? How do I fix it ?

"Cloud Datastore service

Google Cloud Datastore is a fully managed, schemaless database for storing non-relational data.

If you were not expecting to see this page, check out the activation guide for more information."

Comment: What code are you using to call the datastore. Google Cloud Datastore is the interface to access it from outside of the GAE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687671/google-cloud-datastore-vs-google-app-engine

Comment: I am using the API:
DatastoreService store = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();    why ?

Comment: Is all the work from inside GAE? the API is for external calls.

Comment: Does it all run as expected on the local devserver?

Comment: I am not making any external calls and it runs as expected on local devserver.
The issue is, after I deploy on GAE, i see the error message above when i access
http://<my id>.appspot.com

However, I do NOT see the error message when I access:
http://1-dot-<my id>.appspot.com/

why ?

Comment: I solved this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/26475419/850647

Comment: possible duplicate of [New GAE project, get error at appid.appspot.com, but not 1-dot-appid.appspot.com?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457249/new-gae-project-get-error-at-appid-appspot-com-but-not-1-dot-appid-appspot-com)