# New GAE project, get error at appid.appspot.com, but not 1-dot-appid.appspot.com?

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a new GAE project, and deployed it to the server with the appid assigned to me when I created the project (stable-arch-xxx).

Now, when I visit http://stable-arch-xxx.appspot.com/ I get rerouted to https://stable-arch-xxx.appspot.com/ (the HTTPS version) and get this error:

[image: screenshot of google app engine error]

It says "Cloud Datastore service, Google Cloud Datastore is a fully managed, schemaless database for storing non-relational data. If you were not expecting to see this page, check out the activation guide for more information".

However, when I go to http://1-dot-stable-arch-xxx.appspot.com/ it does not redirect, and I get the correct page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have versions setup for your project?

Comment: Yes, it was set to 1, but I changed it to 2-0-test like in [this post (link)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?csw=1#Python_app_yaml_Required_elements) and redeployed, same error, and still accessible at 1-dot-stable-arch-xxx.appspot.com

Comment: Doy our logs show the 500 errors?

Comment: I don't see 500 errors. Interesting find- if you go to the sidebar and go to Compute, App Engine, Versions, you can set a version as the default. I deleted the 2-0-test version, then tried to set version 1 as the default. I always get this error: [picture](http://i.imgur.com/eYHMVGV.png) This is probably the issue, as I don't have any default version set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have a default version set. It seems that the new app engine console is buggy. When I go to the old app engine console (https://appengine.google.com), go into my app, then go to Versions in the sidebar, I can set my current version and everything works fine.

Google should get their act together and fix these very basic bugs if they ever want to compete seriously with AWS, Rackspace, etc.

Comment: How did you create your project? I'd suggest [posting this information over to the public issue tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), a community issue tracking project that Google uses to make sure the community of developers are included and have a voice in how the platform develops.